An error occured on Saving/Creating Sitecore Form
Creating a new Sitecore Form with OOTB field Single-line-text, on saving getting Red alert with message An error Occurred.
In the console getting details

"{"message":"The requested resource does not support http method
'GET'."}"

Using Sitecore Version 10.0 without Form Extension Module.
How to fix this?

Sounds xdb related - might want to check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/28522/237

Please check Sitecore Log files on the CM Server for any errors while saving the form. Additionally, try rebuilding Forms indexes and Sitecore Master Index once and try it out.

Check Sitecore logs and Right-click on your browser window and select Inspect or press F12, Network Tab, fill form again and check the request which got failed. Double confirm your end points (Domains and other urls)
